# How do you convert names in all caps to title case?

Tags: java, string, naming-conventions, converters

Given MARY JANE WATSON, for it to output Mary Jane Watson, it can be done with a little help from

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("MARY JANE WATSON");
```

To cater for names with an apostrophe, it can also be done with

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("MIGUEL O'HARA", ' ', '\'') // gives Miguel O'Hara
```

However, there are other naming conventions e.g. JEAN DEWOLFF -> Jean DeWolff, KENNY MCFARLANE -> Kenny McFarlane, etc. with the 3rd letter capitalised and also there are nobiliary particles like de, di, von, etc., which are not captialised.

How do you write a converter to cater for all these naming conventions to convert names in all caps to title case?

Feel free to solve this with a more powerful until already made instead of relying on `WordUtils`.

Comment: I am not sure how you can solve everything. One of my favorite authors is Charles deLint. I have a first initial and a middle name. Names tend to follow conventions that run in families, and there are a lot of families. And some names are purely individual. Do you remember The Artist Formerly Known As Prince? I don't know how you'd capitalize his name (an unpronounceable symbol).

Comment: One way might be to write an algorithm that handles the majority, then send letters out to everybody with "This is how our computer thinks your name is spelled. Please respond back if we're wrong."

Comment: This is possible, but only to an extent. You can check [Title Case Converter](https://titlecaseconverter.com) which handles some, but not all special cases.

Comment: In your application, why are names in uppercase in the first place? If they were in mixed case it wouldn't be a problem.